# how to store data in vector?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i am new in black berry i have no idea how to store data in blackberry use of vector.
and i need to store this data so please help me.

```
{
    "menu": {
        "id": "Home",
        "menuitem": [
            {
                "type": "form",
                "name": "Order",
                "url": "http://domain/oredr.aspx",
                "Row": [
                    {
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "LB",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "User Name",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "TB",
                                "align": "Right",
                                "send": "Yes",
                                "value": "",
                                "param": "username",
                                "maxlength": "25",
                                "ctype": "Alpha"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "LB",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "Mobile No",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "TB",
                                "align": "Right",
                                "send": "Yes",
                                "value": "",
                                "param": "MobileNo",
                                "maxlength": "10",
                                "ctype": "Numeric"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "Index": "3",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "LB",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "Email ID",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "TB",
                                "align": "Right",
                                "send": "Yes",
                                "value": "",
                                "param": "email",
                                "maxlength": "50",
                                "ctype": "Email"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "Index": "4",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "None",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "BT",
                                "align": "Center",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "Submit",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": "Submit"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "type": "form",
                "name": "Stock",
                "url": "http://domain/stock.aspx",
                "Row": [
                    {
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "LB",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "Select Medium",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "CB",
                                "align": "Right",
                                "send": "Yes",
                                "value": "Select Medium",
                                "param": "medium",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": "",
                                "Item": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Yes"
                                    }, {
                                        "name": "No"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "None",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "BT",
                                "align": "Center",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "Submit",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": "Submit"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "type": "form",
                "name": "Custom",
                "url": "http://domain/custom.aspx",
                "Row": [
                    {
                        "Index": "1",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "LB",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "Offer Type",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "DD",
                                "align": "Right",
                                "send": "Yes",
                                "value": "",
                                "param": "offertype",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": "",
                                "Item": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Marketing"
                                    }, {
                                        "name": "Promotional"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "Index": "2",
                        "Control": [
                            {
                                "type": "None",
                                "align": "Left",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": ""
                            }, {
                                "type": "BT",
                                "align": "Center",
                                "send": "No",
                                "value": "Submit",
                                "param": "",
                                "maxlength": "",
                                "ctype": "Submit"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i am  parsing successfully use json parser.

```
try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(Data.data).getJSONObject("menu");
        JSONArray array = root.getJSONArray("menuitem");

    System.out.println("strMenu=="+strMenu);
    for(int loop=0; loop<array.length(); loop++){
        System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(loop).get("type"));
        System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(loop).get("name"));
        System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(loop).get("url"));
        JSONArray rows = array.getJSONObject(loop).getJSONArray("Row");
        for(int innerLoop=0; innerLoop<rows.length();innerLoop++){
            System.out.println(rows.getJSONObject(innerLoop).get("Index"));
            JSONArray controll = rows.getJSONObject(innerLoop).getJSONArray("Control");
            for(int innermostLoop =0; innermostLoop<controll.length(); innermostLoop++){
                System.out.println(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("type"));
                System.out.println(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("align"));
                System.out.println(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("send"));
                System.out.println(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("value"));
                System.out.println(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("param"));
                System.out.println(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("maxlength"));
                System.out.println(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("ctype"));


                if(controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).get("type").equals("DD"))
                {
                    JSONArray item=controll.getJSONObject(innermostLoop).getJSONArray("Item");
                    for(int i=0;i<item.length();i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(item.getJSONObject(i).get("name"));
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("ZZZZZZZZ error ZZZZZZZ");
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

i want to store all data in a single vector.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
Vector vector = new Vector();
```

on your for loop, add items to the vector.

```
vector.addElement(new your_object(value_1,value_2......));
```

Comment: new your_object(value_1,value_2......) means please explain me more buddy Signare

Comment: i want to store according to my json data.

Comment: what values you want to store. String type=array.getJSONObject(loop).get("type"); then add that String type to your vector in place of value_1. like that.

Comment: please send me complete storing process

Comment: which datas you want to store ?

Comment: then add all the datas to the vector.